# Get Data from List in List and compare with other list

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I got following problem which I can't solved :(

Scenario: I have a list with Ingredients and I want to compare it with a recipes list which holds a list of ingredients depending on the recipes.

```
List<RecipeList> recipesList = [
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Cake", itemNames: ["banana", "appel"]),
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Soup", itemNames: ["potatato", "egg"]),
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Sandwich", itemNames: ["Toast", "Sausage", "Ketchup"]),
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Pizza", itemNames: ["Tomato", "Mushroom"]),
];

 List inventory = ["coke", "egg", "banana", "apple"];


class RecipeList {
  String? recipeName;
  List<String>? itemNames;

  RecipeList({this.recipeName, this.itemNames});
}
```

I am thankful for any help or idea :D!

Thank you very much for your help,
ReeN

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the output to be? Do you want to print the recipes where the `itemNames` is a subset of the `inventory`?

Comment: Hey @mmcdon20 thank you for the quick reply. :D
Yes exactly I want to output all recipes which ingredients are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by changing the inventory to be a `Set<String>`. This will allow you to more efficiently check for subsets using the `containsAll` method.

You can then call `where` on the `recipesList` to get all of the elements where the `inventory` contains all of the `itemNames` for the given `RecipeList` object.

See implementation below:

```dart
List<RecipeList> recipesList = [
  // fixed misspelling of "apple"
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Cake", itemNames: ["banana", "apple"]),
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Soup", itemNames: ["potatato", "egg"]),
  RecipeList(
      recipeName: "Sandwich", itemNames: ["Toast", "Sausage", "Ketchup"]),
  RecipeList(recipeName: "Pizza", itemNames: ["Tomato", "Mushroom"]),
];

// change inventory to a Set<String>
Set<String> inventory = {"coke", "egg", "banana", "apple"};

class RecipeList {
  String? recipeName;
  List<String>? itemNames;

  RecipeList({this.recipeName, this.itemNames});
}

void main() {
  var results =
      recipesList.where((v) => inventory.containsAll(v.itemNames ?? []));

  for (var result in results) {
    print(result.recipeName);
  }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much!So quick and helpful :D. 

  // fixed misspelling of "apple"
just made my day hahaha xD

Answer (score 0):

one of the approaches that you can take is to loop over the `recipesList` , hold every element in hand, then access the list in that element and loop over it then you can do whatever comparison you want with the `inventory` list

Comment: Thank you for the help :D. In this case I used the way of mmcdon20 but your way was the one I was trying ^^. Thank you for the quick reply!